# Will 12" studs work for a TV mount designed for 16" stud mounting?

Tags: mounting, television

I've moved into a new location and I have 12" studs rather than the 16" studs my TV mount was designed for.  The TV mount comes with lag bolts (M8x55).  Getting the lag bolts and pilot holes drilled don't seem to be a problem; the mount is around 25 lbs and my TV is around 35 lbs.  I know that in a broader situation (e.g., 24" studs) I'd want a plywood backing behind the mount.  Am I correct that I shouldn't need one in this case with the studs being closer together as long as the lag bolts are correctly placed in the center of the studs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't told us what mount you're referring to, but most aren't designed for specific stud centers. Instead, they have a range of available mounting area (and many will accommodate 24" centers as well). It's very likely that your mount will work just fine on 12" centers.

You should be able to put a tape measure on the mount and verify. Can you position two bolts 12" apart? If so, the only question is whether you'll be able to mount the TV exactly where you want it, or if you'll have to shift to the side a bit.

Comment: And if not: attach 1x3 boards   to studs, attach mount to boards.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned with whether or not the load is functionally different.  The mount mentions 16" and says "if not 16, you may need a plywood board".  The holes are broad and the mount does have a range; I was wondering if the load would be higher or lower on 12" centers for the same weight.

Comment: The same weight, distributed across the same number of studs, should be the same independent of the stud locations. The plywood is typically used in situations where the mount does not fall on the studs.

Comment: That, and we're talking about 35 lbs. I can't imagine a scenario where that much weight would be an issue. It would probably hang fine with one stud and a couple hollow wall anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work on anything less however you might want to move it one and a half inch right or left. With [commercial toggles](http://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-1-4-in-x-2-1-2-in-Toggle-Bolts/3183831) it doesn't matter. They hold up to 280lbs on drywall.

Also remember you will usually have 3-4" of play. If articulated then you need to be center unless your willing to a lot more for a adjustable wall mount plate.

Comment: That 280 lbs. claim makes me chuckle. It implies that I could screw a chair to the wall and have a seat. Maybe in 5/8" drywall with weight dead tight against the wall and which never moves. I'd cut that by 75% for this use case.